# How to call a header button from home screen thats within tab.naviagtor

Tags: react-native

I have this in my App.js:

```
<NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Login"
  screenOptions={{
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },
    headerTintColor: '#000',
    headerTitleStyle: {  fontSize:12,},
  }}>
      <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={NavTabs}
          options={{ title: 'POLLER', headerLeft: ()=> <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{marginLeft:30,}} name="chart-box-outline" color={'#000000'} size={30} />, headerRight: () => <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{marginLeft:30,}} name="refresh" color={'#000000'} size={30} />,  
  }}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

And the NavTabs as so:

```
 <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Feed"
    screenOptions = {({ route }) =>({
      headerShown: false,
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#000000',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: '#BDBDBD',
      tabBarStyle: [
        {
          display: "flex"
        },
        null
      ],
      tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => 
      screenOptions(route, color),
    })}>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="HomeStack"
      component={Home}
      options={{
        tabBarLabel: 'Home',
        tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
          <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
        ),
      }}
    />
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
```

So when I go to the Home screen I get the tabNavigator at the bottom, but this line as you can see has a refresh material icon:

```
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={NavTabs}
    options={{ title: 'POLLER', headerLeft: ()=> <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{marginLeft:30,}} name="chart-box-outline" color={'#000000'} size={30} />, headerRight: () => <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{marginLeft:30,}} name="refresh" color={'#000000'} size={30} />,  
  }}
  />
```

My question is how do I call a function in the Home screen with this material icon set in the App.js, I understand it needs touchableopacity, I will add that soon as I get understanding of how to call the refresh button in the home screen and hit a function in the home screen

I tried this in the Home Screen but nothing shows in the header:

```
useEffect(() => {
navigation.setOptions({
    headerLargeTitle: true,
    headerRight: () => (
        
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginRight:15,}} onPress={null}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="refresh" color={"#000000"} size={26} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
       
    ),
});
}, [navigation, route]);
```